# Is there a way to tell chronos-etu which timezone to use?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using [chronos-etu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chronos-etu?activeTab=explore) in my app to achieve something similar to [aps-iot-extensions-demo](https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io/). The issue I'm facing is for some reason in my app TimeSlider renders the scale in UTC timezone instead of my local timezone.

I tried to pass dates in the same format as in the demo example (e.g. '2023-08-01' and '2023-08-31') but the result is the same - the scale starts from '2023-07-31 21:00:00' as I'm in the +3 timezone.